# How to run program through console in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm building my first Android application in Android Studio and the switch over from Eclipse is pretty confusing. I'm just trying to test one of my classes through the console to see if it's methods work, but when I click the run button like in Eclipse it is trying to force me to run the application on a device. I just want to test it on the console. How do I allow myself to input and see output through the console on Android Studio?

Thanks, and sorry for the dumb question. Gyazo screenshots appreciated.

This is the test that I'm trying to run. Pretty generic stuff.

[Here are the buttons I'd thought you'd use to run your program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ap5X.png)

[Here's what pops up. The only option under the drop down is that device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwOSl.png)

```
    Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input molecule 1's formula");
    Molecule woah = new Molecule(test.next());
    System.out.println(woah.toString());

    System.out.println("Input molecule 2's molecular mass");
    Molecule crazy = new Molecule("", test.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(crazy);

    System.out.println("Input molecule 3's molecular formula and mass");
    Molecule wow = new Molecule(test.next(), test.nextDouble());
```

Comment: The device being your UI, for input?

Answer (score 1):

I think Android Studio is wired to fire up a device (or emulator) every time you press "start".

I would either try and test stuff on the device itself (for example: have the result be displayed using the "Toast" android class)

OR (the better option in my opinion):

Write JUnit tests! 
That will enable you to test parts of your code, 
and you'll have tests in your project, which are always a good idea :)

And on a side note:

While Android is technically written in Java, it is a very different framework, and programming for Android is different in many ways than simple JAVA.
Usually, you'd encounter such advise when dealing with stuff that's unique to mobile devices, such as battery life awareness, limited memory issues and so on...

However, in this case, I'd think twice about using classes such as "scanner", since they don't really serve a purpose in the Android framework.. 
If you're using it for a system test - fine.
But if you're writing a part of your application, I would suggest using the Android UI (layouts, textboxes and all that jazz).

Good luck! :)